# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error:visual studio on Mac m1

Tags: c++

hello this is my first program on c++ visual studio on Mac m1,
and I m receiving this error

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.816 seconds`[Running] cd "/Users/nezhadjavadali/Documents/AI/C++/" && g++ first.cpp -o first && "/Users/nezhadjavadali/Documents/AI/C++/"first
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.816 seconds
```

and this the main code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "hello ali";

    return 0;
}
```

please give me a hint.

Comment: The code you show, is it the `first.cpp` source file referenced by the build command? Is it the actual code that the compiler tries to build? If you navigate to `/Users/nezhadjavadali/Documents/AI/C++/` in a terminal, and do `cat first.cpp` is it the file you expect it to be?

Comment: Seem like you use "Visual Studio Code" (not the same as Visual Studio). A common problem is that "save the file before compiling" is not in the default settings.